# How to creating a single endpoint with multiple endpoints connecting to it

Tags: java, api, jpa, spring-boot, endpoint

I am trying to create the following tables for getting user information when a user is registering.

[image]

From the tutorials that i have read over the internet i need to create four entity classes namely USER,USER_DETAILS,ROLE and USER_ROLE which i have done. However my problem is when i want to create a user in my application do i have to have 4 different post methods or is there a way i can add the user data in one go to the relevant tables.

I would like to be able to post data to a single url and all these table with there foreign keys be filled at once when a user gives all the details.

Something like :

```
{
    "userName": “ME",
    "password": "1234”,
    “DOB": “1988-05-12",
    "email": “test@test.org",
    “role": “admin",
    "country": "Ireland",
    "registrationLocation": "Dublin",
    "timeStamp": "18-01-2018T12:23:08"
}
```

posting it to a single url such as : localhost:8080/live/api

This is my code:

**UserDetails**

```
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private Users user;


@NotBlank
private String DOB;

public UserDetails() {
}

public UserDetails( String DOB) {
    this. DOB = DOB;
}

public String getDOB() {
    return DOB;
}

public void setTitle(String DOB) {
    DOB = DOB;
}


 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)


 @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users", 
uniqueConstraints = 
          {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username")
        }

)

public class Users implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long userID;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "Please enter between 8 and 100 characters.")
private String password;

@NotBlank
private String username;

private Role role;

public Users() {

}

public Users(long userID, String password, String username, Role role) {
    this.userID = userID;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
}


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "roleID")
public Role getRoles() {
    return role;
}

public long getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(long userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}



}
```

**UserRole**

```
@Entity
public class UserRole implements Serializable {


    private Role role;

    private Users user;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(Role role, Users user) {
        this.role = role;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



}
```

**Controller class method**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/usermanagement/users")
public Response createUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users user){
    return userService.AddUser(user);

 }
```

Comment: Where is your java code? Did you attempt the problem? see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: let me past my classes

Answer (score 0):

You can post all the relevant information to 1 endpoint like you have given an example and then from UserService class (an Impl class preferably) you can call all the relevant methods to save the relevant details. For example,

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

public Response addUser(Users user){
   //get details from Users and populate to entities User and UserDetails.
   // Save User and UserDetails. Return Response
 }
 }
```

Comment: thank you, however how can i seperate the data such that it can be saved accordingly. My aim is to post data in one json object in a post body.